# Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() despite everything looking fine

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I have an array that's being passed to a foreach and even though I've used foreach's hundred's of times before, I can't figure out why this is giving me the error, `Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()`

```
switch($searchby){
    case 0: // Name
        print_r($data);
        foreach($data as $key => $i){
            if($key % 2 == 0 && $i == $searchfor){
                $success = TRUE;
                $matches[] = array('name' => $i, 'value' => $data[$key+1]);
            }
        }
        break;
}
```

The `print_r` prints a normal array, for instance (an actual example):

```
Array
(
    [0] => Username
    [1] => 4567
    [2] => Password
    [3] => 4567
    [4] => Name
    [5] => 4567
    [6] => Age
    [7] => 4567
    [8] => Country
    [9] => 4567
    [10] => Type
    [11] => Register
)
```

---- Since apparently it works, here's the entire callstack with the stack marked with `<------`: ----

```
/// Main.js ///
$("form#Register").submit(function () {
    event.preventDefault();
    $.post("php/proc.php",{'Command':'registerUser','Data':$(this).serialize()},function (data) { // <---- Original call
        console.log(data);
    });
    return false;
});


// proc.php //

echo json_encode($MainLib->registerUser($db, $data)); // <--------- #1

class MainLib 
{
    public function registerUser($db, $data){
        $pword = $this->hashpword($db, $result1[0]['value'], $result2[0]['value'], 'Register'); // <---------------- #2
    }

    public function hashpword($db, $data){
        $uname = $this->searchData(0,'Username',$data); // <----------- #3
        $pword = $this->searchData(0,'Password',$data);
        $type = $this->searchData(0,'Type',$data);
        switch($type){
            case 'Register':
                $salt = uniqid(rand(0,99999999),TRUE);
                $db->query("UPDATE `Users` SET `salt`='" . $salt . "' WHERE `Username`='" . $uname . "'");
                echo "UPDATE `Users` SET `salt`='" . $salt . "' WHERE `Username`='" . $uname . "'";
                break;

            $result = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `Users` WHERE `Username`='" . $uname . "'");

            while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){
                $salt = $row['salt'];
            }
        }
        $salt = base_convert($salt, 26, 10);
        $pword = base_convert($pword, 26, 10);
        $new_pword = $pword * $salt;
        $new_pword = base_convert($new_pword, 10, 17);
        $pword = hash('sha512',$new_pword);
        return $pword;
    }


    public function searchData($searchby, $searchfor, $data){
        $success = FALSE;

        switch($searchby){
            case 0: // Name
            print_r($data);
                foreach($data as $key => $i){ // <--------- ERROR
                    if($key % 2 == 0 && $i == $searchfor){ 
                        $success = TRUE;
                        $matches[] = array('name' => $i, 'value' => $data[$key+1]);
                    }
                }
                break;
            case 1: // Value
                foreach($data as $key => $i){
                    if($key % 2 == 0 && $data[$key+1] == $searchfor){
                        $success = TRUE;
                        $matches[] = array('name' => $i, 'value' => $data[$key+1]);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

        if($success) return $matches;
        return FALSE;

    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure the error is relevant to that specific line?

Comment: Just make sure data is array before to use it in a foreach.

Comment: The error must be caused by some code that you didn't post.  I copied and your code and recreated your array and I don't receive any errors on the `foreach()`.

Comment: Yes, it is, that's the exact line the problem is coming from. The data is definitely an array, as seen in the `print_r($data)` return.

Comment: what is the value of `$searchfor`?

Comment: Thank @NickCoons, let me check again, although I don't think there is. Could it be a php.exe issue?

Comment: The value of `$searchfor` changes depending on what's being searched for, but it would be one of the odd numbers of the array (`Username`, `Password`, etc)

Comment: it works fine with me. i think there's a problem with your `$data`. can you please put `die()` after the print_r just to verify the value of that variable and no other variables are being printed?

Comment: `die()` cuts it off right after the array exactly as shown in the post.

Comment: and as @vainglory07 suggested, also put one after the foreach loop to check for future loops causing you problems.

Comment: Alright, @scrowler, one moment. And also, I added the callstack plus the corresponding code, marked with arrows.

Comment: @scrowler, do you mean to put a `die()` after the foreach loop or a `print_r()` after it? or after the first line of it?

Comment: where you've got the break after the foreach, put a die before it. At the very least this will tell you that your problem is **definitely** in that foreach structure

Comment: after trying to put die(), does the value of `$data` is still the same?

Comment: @Vainglory07 Yeah, everything is exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

this might not be the right answer, i just want to know if this will suppress the error:

```
switch($searchby){
case 0: // Name
    if(is_array($data)) { //--> add this validation
        print_r($data);
        foreach($data as $key => $i){
            if($key % 2 == 0 && $i == $searchfor){
                $success = TRUE;
                $matches[] = array('name' => $i, 'value' => $data[$key+1]);
            }
        }
    } else {
        die('Invalid Array!');
    }
    break;
}
```

try to add `is_array` condition if it could still print the value of `$data` and able to continue your script.

Comment: `is_array()` returns a `1` but the function is skipped. I ran `print_r(is_array($data));` right before the `if(is_array($data)) {` and it returned a `1`